# How to add your own Javascript to another website

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarks

How can I add a javascript file to the bookmark bar so that when I click on that file that is set in the bookmark bar then the javascript gets executed on the current webpage. Like if I had written a javascript file to run on a webpage and I want to set it to the bookmark bar of chrome and when I click on it then the javascript gets executed on the current webpage

if this is the code so how can i add it

```
let added = document.getElementById('name');
let text = 'Example Singh';
added.value = text;
```

now I want to add this code to a website in the bookmark bar of google chrome

Comment: You can try something like tampermonkey for chrome. Its is available as a chrome extension.

Comment: One word "Bookmarklet"

Comment: What you're describing is a "bookmarklet". Just wrap your code in `javascript:void(function(){ ... your code }())`

Comment: ok but can i add my own extension to chrome and then i run it then will it work

Comment: @adiga no need to wrap the code in a function or IIFE

Comment: @phuzi I thought it was needed for multiline code.

Comment: @adiga I've never created a bookmarklet as more than a single line of code

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Bookmarklet](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/bookmarklets-perform-common-web-page-tasks). It is a bookmark that runs a small piece of JavaScript.

So if you add a bookmark to your bookmarks and then set the URL to contain URL encoded JavaScript prefixed with `javascript:`, when you click the bookmark it will run the bookmark(let)'s JS.

Given your code above you should set a bookmarklet with the following "URL"

```
javascript:document.getElementById('name').value='Example Singh';
```

More information about bookmarklets can be found [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/bookmarklets-perform-common-web-page-tasks)

Comment: `javascript:void(function(){ //code }())` for multiple lines of code

Comment: @adiga There's no need to wrap the code in an IIFE. The above Bookmarklet will work as is,

Comment: can you please suggest a webpage where i can have an article to add it .Your talks are going over of my mind

Comment: @SHIVANSHUSINGH see the link in my comment on your question.

Comment: @phuzi where is the link

Comment: @SHIVANSHUSINGH My apologies, I thought I had included a link. Added it to my answer instead.

Comment: @phuzi  I need for chrome then?

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/188842?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome without extensions:

1. create any bookmark
2. right click on it - `Edit...`
3. replace `url` field with javascript `javascript:alert('hello');`
4. pressing it executes javascript on currently opened page

To toggle bookmarks bar on a page, use ctrl + shift + B